# How do I release my directshow filter so that one without any programing environment can install successfully?

Tags: directshow, release-management

It now works on my computer, how to ensure it works on other computers?

Is there any best practice ?

Answer (score 0):

What's worked well for me so far is to create a setup and deployment project In Visual Studio. The important thing is to be sure to package all dependencies i.e like 3rd party DLLs if you use any, and also to add the corresponding merge modules related to your VC runtime to the project as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Adding the merge module, you don't have to download the vc runtimes or [redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=32bc1bee-a3f9-4c13-9c99-220b62a191ee&displaylang=en) on other computers. This step I've always had to do manually in my experience.

Also, be sure to select the vsdrfCOMSelfReg Register option on the Properties Window for each of your DirectShow filters to handle COM registration during installation.

Comment: what's the terminology for this ? I think there should be some kind of standard for deploying c/c++ projects.